# Main menu gets replaced when second menu is created

Tags: menus

I have a menu (main menu) and i call it with `<?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?>`. It works normally, and is set to Primary Location.

But when I create another menu, the new one replaces the main menu. The theme is custom made, so obsiously is something I'm missing about WP menus. Aany help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your second menu has the same id as your main menu when you registry these menus.
One more thing, make sure that you go to Dashboard > Appearance > Menus, tick to the box Location for the menus properly.